# randomize with a condition

Tags: python, list

So in python, I have a list like so

`['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b']`

I was wondering if it is possible for me to randomize it so that there's no way for the values that share the same number (i.e. 1a and 1b) to be beside each other after I randomize them.

So for example the final list would come out like something like this:

`['1a', '3b', '4b', '2a', '3a', '6a', '5a', '1b', '5b', '4a', '6b', '2b']`

Thank you.

Comment: How random do you need the randomization to be?

Comment: What is your current attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best approach but it does what you want:

```
from random import shuffle

unsorted_ls = ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b']

while True:
    shuffle(unsorted_ls)

    checker = False
    for i in range(1, len(unsorted_ls)):
        if unsorted_ls[i - 1][0] == unsorted_ls[i][0]:
            checker = True
            break

    if checker == False:
        break
```

Yet whenever you run this code you will get different results.

Comment: You should break out of the nested loop when you set `checker`

Comment: Yeah it could reduce the number of iterations

Answer (score 1):

One way about this would be to construct a new table-like dictionary that excludes the 'similar candidate' for each item:

```py
{'1a': ['2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '1b': ['2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '2a': ['1a', '1b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '2b': ['1a', '1b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '3a': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '3b': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '4a': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '4b': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b'],
 '5a': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '6a', '6b'],
 '5b': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '6a', '6b'],
 '6a': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b'],
 '6b': ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b']}
```

Call this object `y`. You can construct it like so:

```py
x = ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b']
y = {}
for a in x:
    y[a] = [i for i in x if not i.startswith(a[0])]
```

You can then pick from the values of each element based on the last-seen element:

```py
import random

len_new = 10  # Desired length of new list
new = []
last_val = random.choice(list(y))  # Initial pick
for _ in range(len_new):
    last_val = random.choice(y[last_val])
    new.append(last_val)
```

Result:

```py
>>> print(new)
['6b', '3b', '2a', '3a', '4a', '2a', '6b', '5a', '4b', '1b']
```

**Downsides**:

- Memory inefficiency.  For a very large `x`, your `y` "table" becomes large very quickly. But for small inputs such as yours, this is not an issue. You could cut down on this by *not* constructing the full `y` up front, but rather creating just the needed table row at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from random import shuffle

def randomize(list_):
    shuffle(list_)
    for n, n_plus_1 in zip(list_, list_[1:]):
        if n[0] == n_plus_1[0]:
            return randomize(list_)
    return list_

list_ = ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b']
print(randomize(list_))
```

output:

```
['2b', '1a', '4b', '3b', '5a', '3a', '6a', '2a', '6b', '4a', '1b', '5b']
```

The output will obviously be different every time, but adjacent items will never have the same leading number.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a high percentage of items that have the same prefix, it would be preferable to use a backtracking approach. Note that a recursive approach is not recommended for this as it would quickly hit recursion depth limits  for lists that have a few hundred items

```
from random import choice
def shuffle(A):
    result    = []
    remaining = A.copy()
    while len(result)<len(A):
        eligible = [v for v in remaining if not result or v[0]!=result[-1][0]]
        if eligible:                         # pick from eligibles
            selected  = choice(eligible)
            remaining.remove(selected)
            result.append(selected)
        else:
            remaining.append(result.pop(-1)) # backtrack
    return result

        
A = ['1a', '1b', '2a', '2b', '3a', '3b', '4a', '4b', '5a', '5b', '6a', '6b']

print(shuffle(A))
# ['5b', '6b', '3b', '6a', '2b', '1a', '2a', '4b', '3a', '4a', '5a', '1b']
```

On the other hand, if there are few common prefixes or the list is small, then a simpler trial-and-error approach on the whole list may be sufficient:

```
from random import sample
def shuffle(A):
    while True:
        result = sample(A,len(A))
        if all(a[0]!=b[0] for a,b in zip(result,result[1:])):
            return result

print(shuffle(A))
# ['6b', '2b', '6a', '3a', '4b', '1b', '5a', '1a', '2a', '3b', '4a', '5b']
```

In both cases, if it is not possible to obtain a permutation that meets the condition, the functions will never return (e.g. A = ['1a','1b']) so you may want to add a validation for that.

```
from collections import Counter
def shuffle(A):
    maxFreq   = max(Counter(a[0] for a in A).values())
    if maxFreq*2-1>len(A): return
    ...
```